# Remove relationship from ModelA to ModelB but do NOT remove from ModelB to ModeA in Django ManyToMany Fields

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a this model structue,

```py
ModelA:
  model_b = models.ManyToManyField(
        ModelB,
        blank=True,
    )
  ...

ModelB:
  ...
```

Now I want to delete the relationship from ModelA to ModelB using, `model_a.model_b.clear()` but I want `model_b.model_a_set.all()` to still retain the ModelB object. It's kinda I want independent OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship. How can I implement it?

PS: In my case ModelB always have relation to a single object of ModelA, if this can reduce the complexity of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a fk relation on ModelB

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelA,
        # You may want other kinds of cascading mode here
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

If this is the case (and after migration), you will then populate this field with data from the original m2m field.

```
for model_a in ModelA.objects.all():
    model_a.model_b.update(model_a=model_a)
```

Then you are free to remove the original m2m field